# Upper bound on size of obstruction set for wye-delta-wye reducible graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-minors

A graph is *$Y \Delta Y$-reducible* if it can be reduced to an empty graph by the following operations:

- $Y \leftrightarrow\Delta$ transforms;
- Replacing multiple edges with single edges (parallel reduction);
- Contracting an edge, provided that at least one endpoint has degree at most $2$ (series reduction).
- Removal of loops.

It has been shown that a minor of a $Y \Delta Y$-reducible graph is also $Y \Delta Y$-reducible. Hence, by the Robertson-Seymour theorem, there is a finite obstruction set of 'forbidden minors', which includes the seven graphs of the Petersen family.

In $2006$, Yaming Yu [proved](http://www.emis.de/journals/EJC/Volume_13/PDF/v13i1r7.pdf) that there are at least $68897913659$ forbidden minors, and mentions that it is an open problem whether there are more.

I ask for an upper bound on the number of forbidden minors. The strength of the Robertson-Seymour theorem suggests that this could be incredibly large.